# Limit of a complex valued function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = (\frac{z}{\bar{z}})^{2}$ , be a complex valued function , we need to prove that $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$ does not exists.

So , to prove that its limit doesn't exists , we approach (0,0) from 2 different paths and say that , since the limits of 2 different paths are not equal , thus the limit does'not exists. (As for the existence of the limit , limit along different paths should be equal).

So in this case we approach along the $X-axis$ and then the $Y-axis$ and see that the limit value differs ,

But the solution says , taking these paths isn't sufficient to say that the limit does'not exists. Hence in the solution the line through the origin , $Y=X$ is taken to approach the origin.

Can anyone explain me this ?

Comment: Why do you think the limit differs on the $x, y$ axes?

Comment: If $z \to 0$ along the real axis, then $z = \bar{z}$ and $f(z) = 1$ for all such $z$. If $z \to 0$ along the imaginary axis, then $z = -\bar{z}$ so that $f(z) = (-1)^2 = 1$ for such $z$. In other words, the limit will be the same along both these paths, not different as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not sufficient because if you approach $0$ along the $y$-axis, the function is constant and is again $1$.

Indeed
$$
\lim_{t\to0}f(it)=\lim_{t\to0}\left(\frac{it}{-it}\right)^{\!2}=1
$$

The hint is to try
$$
\lim_{t\to0}f(t+it)=
\lim_{t\to0}\left(\frac{t+it}{t-it}\right)^{\!2}=
\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^{\!2}=\dots
$$

A different way to do it is to consider $\def\theta{\vartheta}z=re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ fixed and $r\to0$: then
$$
\lim_{r\to0}f(re^{i\theta})=
\lim_{r\to0}\left(\frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{-i\theta}}\right)^{\!2}=
e^{4i\theta}
$$
which clearly depends on $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you need to approach from two paths to show that the limit does not exist. My comment explains why your two paths give the same limit, and thus does not show the limit does not exist.

Hint: Approach from the real (or imaginary) axis and then approach along the path consisting of complex numbers of the form $z = x+ ix$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Thinking of the complex plane in terms of geometry, $z$ and $\bar{z}$ have the same magnitude but have opposite imaginary components. So when you divide by $\bar{z}$, this is effectively making the magnitude $1$ and making the angle double of the angle of $z$ (in the complex plane), and then you are squaring which doubles the angle again. Can you see why are there are only finitely many angles which will make this limit equal to $1$, which is presumably the limit you already calculated for traveling along the real and imaginary axis toward 0?