# Find $\lim_{z \to 0} \left(z/\bar{z} \right)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the limit $\lim_{z \to 0} \left(\frac{z}{\overline{z}} \right)^2$, if we take $z=re^{i \Theta}$ note that

$$\left(\frac{z}{\overline{z}} \right)^2=\left(\frac{re^{i\Theta}}{re^{-i\Theta}} \right)^2=e^{4i\Theta}$$

This may help clarify things a bit, but I still don't see the value of the limit. Any suggestions?

Comment: This means the limit is depending on the argument of $z$, so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\frac{z}{\bar{z}}: DNE$ (Does Not Exist)

The limit exists if and only if it is the same regardless of what path you use to approach the limit value.
As a corollary, if you find 2 or mor paths that yield different values for the limit, the limit does not exist.

Take $z=R+Ii$, where $R$ and $I$ are the real and imaginar parts.
Then $\bar{z}=R-Ii$.

$$\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\bigg(\frac{z}{\bar{z}}\bigg)^2=\lim\limits_{R, I \to 0}\frac{(R+Ii)^2}{(R-Ii)^2}=\lim\limits_{R, I \to 0}\frac{R^2+2RIi-I^2}{R^2-2RIi-I^2}$$

If you approach on the path $R=0$ (i.e. along the Imaginary axis) you get:
$$\lim\limits_{R, I \to 0}\frac{R^2+2RIi-I^2}{R^2-2RIi-I^2}=\lim\limits_{I \to 0}\frac{0+0-I^2}{0-0-I^2}=1$$

On the other hand, if you approach on the path $I=R$ (i.e. along the $\frac{\pi}{4}$ line) you get:
$$\lim\limits_{R, I \to 0}\frac{R^2+2RIi-I^2}{R^2-2RIi-I^2}=\lim\limits_{I \to 0}\frac{I^2+2IIi-I^2}{I^2-2IIi-I^2}=\lim\limits_{I \to 0}\frac{2I^2i}{-2I^2i}=-1$$

The limits along two different paths yield different results, therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: Don't duplicate previous answers to duplicate questions.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382279/limit-of-a-complex-valued-function), and post your answer there if it adds anything unique to the answers there.

Answer (score 1):

Recall in your multivariable class, why the limit of $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ does not exist as $(x,y)\to\textbf{0}$, even if you use polar part, you get $\lim_{r\to0}\cos^2\theta$. This means the limit is mainly determined by how does your $x$ enter to the origin.

In this case, you can also prove the limit exist by considering how does your $z$ tends to origin in different way (you at least has two trivial ways already).

Comment: Don't duplicate previous answers to duplicate questions.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382279/limit-of-a-complex-valued-function), and post your answer there if it adds anything unique to the answers there.  You can delete your comment above, as well.